# Restricting Plot3D to an area inside parametrically defined region

Tags: plotting, regions, visualization

I have a region specified as a simple closed curve, suitable for `ParametricPlot` (as in this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144041/how-to-plot-the-field-of-values-numerical-range-of-a-matrix/152330#152330)).

What is the easiest way to restrict 3D plot to only plot points inside this region?

An example application is here -- I'm plotting resolvent and range of matrix as separate `Plot3D` and `ParametricPlot`, but I'd like to combine them into a single `Plot3D` by using `RegionFunction` argument. However, that takes a region membership function, but I instead have a curve of the boundary.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
n = 3;

badMat[eps_] := Module[{mat},
   mat = RotateLeft@IdentityMatrix[n];
   mat[[n, 1]] = eps;
   mat
   ];

fval[mat_?SquareMatrixQ, t_?NumericQ] /; 
   Internal`EffectivePrecision[mat] < \[Infinity] || 
    InexactNumberQ[t] := 
  Module[{tm, v}, tm = (# + ConjugateTranspose[#])/2 &[mat Exp[I t]];
   v = Quiet[
     Check[First[
       Eigenvectors[tm, 1, 
        Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}]], 
      MaximalBy[Transpose[Eigensystem[tm]], First][[1, -1]], 
      Eigenvectors::arall]];
   (Conjugate[v] . mat . v)/(Conjugate[v] . v)];

pr = {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}};

epsVals = {0.01, .1, .5, .9};

rangePlot[mat_] := 
  With[{eigs = Eigenvalues[mat]}, 
   ParametricPlot[ReIm[fval[mat, t]], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
    Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[10], ColorData[97, 2], 
      Point[ReIm[eigs]]}, PlotRange -> pr]];

resolventPlot[mat_] := Module[{},
   eigs = Eigenvalues[mat];
   c = Norm[mat];
   n = Length[mat];
   spectraPlot = 
    Plot3D[-c Log10[
       First[SingularValueList[
         mat - SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> x + I y, {n, n}], -1, 
         Method -> "Arnoldi", Tolerance -> 0]]], {x, -2, 4}, {y, -4, 
      4}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {-1, 1},
     MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False
     ]
   ];

Print["Matrices"];
Table[MatrixForm[badMat[eps]], {eps, epsVals}]
Print["Resolvents"];
Table[resolventPlot[badMat[eps]], {eps, epsVals}]
Print["Numeric ranges"];
Table[rangePlot[badMat[eps]], {eps, epsVals}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By

```
regs = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics /@ fig2ds
```

we get the 4 regions.

[image]

So we add

```
reg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@ParametricPlot[ReIm[fval[mat, t]] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 2 π}];
regm = RegionMember@reg;
```

and set `RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, regm@{x, y}]`

```
Clear[resolventPlot2];
resolventPlot2[mat_] := Module[{}, eigs = Eigenvalues[mat];
  c = Norm[mat];
  n = Length[mat];
  reg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@
    ParametricPlot[ReIm[fval[mat, t]] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 2 π}];
  regm = RegionMember@reg; 
  spectraPlot = 
   Plot3D[-c Log10[
      First[SingularValueList[
        mat - SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> x + I y, {n, n}], -1, 
        Method -> "Arnoldi", Tolerance -> 0]]], {x, -2, 4}, {y, -4, 
     4}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
    MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, regm@{x, y}]]]
Table[resolventPlot2[badMat[eps]], {eps, epsVals}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the find, `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics` seems like the trick